# dd clone hard drive: Input/Output Error though "chkdsk" says OK

Tags: ntfs, clone, dd

I've used dd to clone hard drives before using 'dd' and a live cd, but have run into a problem.

**The issue:**

dd fails with an "Input/Output Error" on /dev/sda3 , even though windows "check disk" (chkdsk) says it's ok.

**Context:**

- Trying to replace my laptop hard drive w/ a faster one of the same size
- Laptop has NTFS on a 320gb hard drive
- Booting into knoppix
- Knoppix recognizes 'original' drive(`/dev/sda`)
- I am using  a usb connection for ‘new' drive  (irrelevant, but just an fyi)
- Knoppix recognizes the usb drive as `/dev/sdb`
- Using `dd`, as follows:

  dd  if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
- `dd gives the I/O error above at 82Gb (out of 320Gb)
- I then tried  checking each partition as follows and found it failed on `/dev/sda3`:

  ```
  dd  if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/null
  dd  if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/null
  dd  if=/dev/sda3 of=/dev/null
  ```
- I have ran windows xp chkdsk on the offending drive in both "find only" and "find and fix" mode and it reports no errors

**Question**

How can I find and fix the error on my original hard drive partition (i.e. /dev/sda3) so that dd reads it successfully?

Answer (score 3):

Use [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) for that, it's able to read damaged disks.

And chkdsk probably won't find the issue because it only does basic checks of filesystem integrity; by default, it won't check all the partition space for read errors caused by damage.

Comment: The package for ddrescue is gddrescue on ubuntu if that's the livecd you're using. If you just do ddrescue you get dd_rescue which is a different older package.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and my OpenSUSE livecd didn't include ddrescue or Clonezilla.  However, when I checked out the dd manual, I discovered that there was an option "conv=noerror" that allowed dd to continue past the I/O error.

```
dd conv=noerror if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy data to different HDD attempt use special tools. Norton Ghost (commercial) or Clonezilla (opensource) http://clonezilla.org/