# Copying many files without stopping on errors on OSX

Tags: macos, cp, xcopy, teracopy

I need to copy several Gb from an external HD to my main HD and some files will cause errors. If I do this with the finder, it will stop on the first error.

Is there a way to copy everything no matter the errors? Something like copy of [Teracopy](https://www.codesector.com/teracopy) for Windows?

Comment: Well, if an error occurs, you probably don't want to copy that file. Or do you just want to skip the ones where an error occurs? And, actually the better question would be: *Why* do you get those errors? *What* errors are these, even?

Comment: I want to copy all other files, and handle the errors, whatever they are later.

Comment: Which errors are you getting specifically?

Comment: I hope they add the Windows Vista+ feature to finder and keep copying while warning you of errors.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In terminal, type in

```
cp -Rp /Volumes/<source-volume>/<source-user>/<source-folder>/ /Volumes/<destination-volume>/<destination-folder>/
```

Destination folder should be a new folder you are creating.

If you get info on the new folder after running this you can see the folder size increase.

Example

```
cp -Rp /Volumes/Macintosh HD/User/Bob/Desktop/stufftocopy/ /Volumes/external/newfolder
```

It will copy and display errors for anything it can't copy but without stopping.

*If your directory names contain spaces put quotes around the path

Example

```
cp -Rp "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/User/Bob/Desktop/stufftocopy/" /Volumes/external/newfolder
```

Comment: any explanations about -Rp flag?

Comment: This must be different for osx, on linux -Rp means recruse and preserve attributes, nothing to do with errors.

Comment: `man cp` on macOS tells me: "In -R mode, cp will continue copying even if errors are detected."

Comment: FYI in macOS 10.13.6 `man cp` states "In -R mode, copying will terminate if an error is encountered."

Answer (score 5):

You can use `cp` as suggested or `rsync`, but in the case of I/O Error sometimes it won't work.

So in this case, you can use `dd` tool for specific files which were corrupted.

> `dd` stands for “disk duplication”. This is a command-line utility
>   bundled with Mac OS X. A free version for Windows is also available.
>
> Be extremely careful, even if you are familiar with command line,
>   because dd can cause unrecoverable damage to your data if you don’t
>   specify correctly input and output. You have been warned.
>
> The arguments of dd are straight-forward:
>
> - if=path_of_file_with_IO_errors specifies input path
> - of=path_of_clean_copy_to_create specifies output path
> - conv=noerror,sync tells dd to be fault-tolerant
>
> Your output path should not be on the same disk as the damaged file.
>   Actually, you shouldn’t continue using the card or disk with I/O
>   errors, because it’s likely to cause more problems in the future.
>   After recovery the data, you should scrap it or at most use it to
>   store unimportant stuff.
>
> Due to I/O errors, dd can take more time to create the clean copy than
>   a normal copy would take.
>
> But it’s really worth the wait, because now we have a clean file on
>   which we can use our arsenal of diagnostics, preview and video
>   recovery tools.
>
> I/O errors are a serious business, and scrapping the card after
>   recovering the videos is probably the RIGHT THING TO DO. You should
>   also consider that some amount of footage won’t be recovered, or with
>   a less-than-stellar quality.

Source: http://aeroquartet.com/wordpress/2012/06/06/how-to-copy-a-file-with-io-errors/

Example:

```
dd if=/Volumes/CD/broken_movie.avi of=~/Movies/broken_movie.avi conv=noerror,sync
```

See also:

- [Why do we use cp to copy files and not dd? (in unix-derivatives)](https://superuser.com/questions/609211/why-do-we-use-cp-to-copy-files-and-not-dd-in-unix-derivatives)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470160/cant-back-up-sd-card-with-dd-complains-input-output-error
- [dd clone hard drive: Input/Output Error though "chkdsk" says OK](https://superuser.com/questions/35349/dd-clone-hard-drive-input-output-error-though-chkdsk-says-ok)

Comment: I heard the authors of dd wanted to name it cc, for carbon copy, but cc was already taken by the C compiler. I like that better than "disk duplication" 

Answer (score 3):

I use [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php) for exactly this purpose (it's commercial software but has a free trial).  You tell it to copy a file, a folder, or a whole drive or any combination and it finishes to the end of the task and reports problems as it goes.  This doesn't help recover any corrupted files, but it will finish the job no matter how many problems it encounters.

Answer (score 2):

Teracopy has released a Mac version which you can [download](https://apps.apple.com/au/app/teracopy/id1378806557) from the Apple store.

Comment: I was copying to network drives over the SMB protocol. 10s of thousands of files and 10s of GB. I found that it would crash on me often, and I'd have to restart the app. Some files were missed, so I had to switch to the command line. I think this would work great for smaller transfers or transfers that aren't over a network.