# Why do we use cp to copy files and not dd? (in unix-derivatives)

Tags: linux, unix, dd, cp, bsd

For normal file copying in *nix, I've only ever seen people use cp (eg. `cp /mnt/mydevice/myfile ~/myfile`), but I eventually ran into `dd`, which appears to do the exact same thing (`dd if=/mnt/mydevice/myfile of=~/myfile`). I do see that they have some different parameters available (dd seems better at fine-tuned copying), but they appear redundant. Do these tools really do the same thing?

Comment: They do the same things only for regular files. Try for example to copy a directory with `dd`.

Comment: ...or a device (like `/dev/sda`) with `cp`.

Comment: Was your question answered?

Comment: @Eddy_Em, What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer your main question, no, they do not do the same thing.

> dd works on the file you specify, making it able to copy data between
>   devices, or from a device to a file. This is commonly used for moving
>   data if devices specifically are involved (create an iso image from a
>   cd-rom disc for example: dd if=/dev/cdrom of=mycdrom.iso), or backup
>   raw devices (sometimes used in RAC databases: dd if=/dev/raw/raw1
>   of=device_raw1)
>
> cp is used for duplicating file content to a new file or to a new
>   location. things you specifically want there are preservation of
>   ownership, timestamp and mode (rights), and being able to recurse the
>   operation (=being able to copy directories).

[Source](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/544806)

Comment: Ah! Okay, so dd copies the raw file, whereas cp copies the contents (which allows it to for instance copy directories without breaking the filesystem). Thanks!

Comment: @Kruug, I must be missing something because I still don't see what `cp` can do that `dd` cannot. `dd` is also able to *"duplicating file content to a new file or to a new location"* and *"preservation of ownership, timestamp and mode"* right?

Comment: @Pacerier from what I can understand, `cp` is a more focused utility whereas `dd` is more general.  `dd` can do all of what `cp` can do, but `cp` can only do some of what `dd` can do.

Comment: I do not think that the difference is explained clearly enoug. What cp can not do and dd can? And the other way round?

Comment: @Pacerier: `dd` cannot copy multiple files, recurse in directories -  `cp *.txt dest/` and `cp -R mydir/ dest/` are 2 simple examples of things `cp` can do that `dd` cannot.

Answer (score 11):

They do the same thing UNLESS you are specifying one of the options to  `dd` which limits which bytes are copied, such as `seek` or `skip` or `count` or if you use the  `dd` options to mutate bytes such as `conv`. If you aren't using one of these options to  `dd` and are just using the more commonly seen options like `if`, `of`, `bs` then both utilities do the same thing: open both files, read from the input, write to the output until either the input is exhausted or the output cannot accept more bytes.

There is a lot of superstition about reading and writing "device" files stating that you must use `dd` for these, but it is just that, superstition.  `dd` isn't doing anything different, we are just opening files and reading and writing bytes.

Comment: More or less this... if you use of=destiny depending on the device it is, some problems may occur, ex. USB flash disk. I discover that I have to use >> destiny and remove of=xxx parameter for it to work. If I use of=destiny  strange problems occur because I oper with skip and iflags=skip_bytes flag... so, no so much superstition. Needs care and tests because of=destiny may not work correctly in some conditions where >>destiny goes smooth. I wrote a script to save large file to pendrive with steps. Full 400MB copy used to mess sdcard disk partition.